# Laravel : How to eager load specific columns using hasMany function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to get just the `file_name` and `id` column from the `products_type` table using Eager loading but Laravel eager loads an empty result. However, when using belongsTo (see categories relationship below), this technique works.

Where have I gone wrong? Or, most unlikely, is there some problem with the hasMany relationship?

---

**Controller**

```
private function getProducts($category){
    return Products::with(array(
    'types'=>function($q){
            $q->first();
        },//this returns empty array
    'categories'=>function($q)use($category){
            $q->where('name','LIKE',$category);
        }))->get()->toArray();//this returns the correct result
}
```

These are some of the relationship in

**Products model**

```
public function types(){
    return $this->hasMany('Types','product_id')->select(array('products_type.id','products_type.file_name'));
}//doesn't work

public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Categories','category_id')->select(array('categories.id','categories.name'));
}//this works
```

**Types model**

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Products','product_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**tldr;** You always need `foreign key`/`primary key`, involved in the relation, to be selected.

Your `belongsTo` works, because:

```
// Child belongsTo Parent
// so, when you select parent.id,parent.name, Eloquent can match fk-pk:
$child->parent_id == $parent->id;
```

And `hasMany` doesn't work, because:

```
// Parent hasMany Child
$parent->id == $child->parent_id;

// now, when you select child.id,child.name, then:
$child->parent_id; // null, therefore Eloquent can't match the keys
```

So, imagine you select for the `belongsTo` just `parent.name` - then this would not work as well.

That being said, you made the query, fetched correct rows, but didn't allow Eloquent to do its job.